# "define" is not defined when executing suite script 2.0 user event

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suite

I'm trying to execute the suite script2.0 user event

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/record"], function (r) {
    function onAfterSubmit(context) {
}})
```

but while uploading the js file in net [image]suite 
It's not allowing to upload the 2.0 js file

i'm getting define no defined error..

thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your Script record appears to believe it is 1.0. Are you trying to replace a 1.0 Script with a new 2.0 one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't being recognized as SS2. You need a space between the `*` and the `@N...` in the JSDoc

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'],
    function(r){


        function onAfterSubmit(context){

            log.debug('After Submit Triggered');

        }

    return {
    afterSubmit: onAfterSubmit
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying thing that I have run into with 2.0, but it is because your name on the Script File needs to end in ".js"  This should fix it